# What is the determinant of the matirx

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

I solved part (a) when we substitut Av=Bv i get that v is also eigen vector of B corresponding eigen value can  nay help me with part (b)

Comment: since one of the eigen value is zero so the determinat of B is zero is  i am right

Comment: Zero is not an eigenvalue of A. Hint: Vieta's formula.

Comment: but zero is eigen value of B

Comment: Please don’t post crucial parts of your question as images. They’re not searchable and are inaccessible to people who use screen readers. Take the time to type this information in and it’s more likely that someone will take their time to help you.